How to inspect GUI elements (buttons, fields, forms) in Linux and automate, control them from Python script?
There are some tools to simulate users actions (moving mouse, clicking buttons, filling forms and so on) in Linux, like we do it in Windows with Python and pywinauto or pyautogui libraries.
On Linux such tools are ldtp, xdotool, wmctrl, but they do it by desktop coordinates.
But is there a tool like "inspect.exe" in Windows to find specific id-s and selectors, automationID-s of each child GUI-element (of each button, field, form, and so on) of the opened windows to automate them?
Xwininfo is not enough, while it provides only windows ids without buttons and fields info.
How to get the ids of the buttons, fields, forms to manipulate them, not only windows ids.
Let's talk first of all about Mint and Alt Linux with MATE (Xorg-based GUI, not Wayland).

With the help og GTK Inspector I've found the buttons inside the Calc window. Now need to understand, how to cntrol them.

This works on Windows it features a standard API, called win32, for drawing applications UI.
In Linux there was libX11 in the past, then libXCB, and for a while GUI toolkits used X11 for drawing until it wasn't enough and ultimately they switched to compositing the UI manually using raw paint calls, or OpenGL/Vulkan which means such a tool for Linux simply cannot exist. Probably there are tools for individual toolkits but then you need to spill out what you're interested in, because nowadays we still have applications using X11, then we have GTK2/GTK3/GTK4 (largely incompatible) and Qt5/6 (the fifth version is on its last legs and in maintenance mode but many applications still have not been ported to Qt6), TCL/TK and WxWidgets.
TLDR: you must be interested in a specific toolkit and work from there.

As well, as i know, MATE is now on GTK3 mostly.  But i'll be happy with any possibilities for beginning. GTK3 with the help of GTK Inspector or QT - any way to control any of these...
